# Using jQuery to perform .load on originating page div, from floatbox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 pages, we'll call them Page A, B, & C.

On Page A, Page C loads into a div. Also on Page A, there's a link-click that opens Page B with Floatbox (like a popup).

On Page B, there's an onClick function that should reload Page C into the div that is located on page A (underneath the floatbox popup).

The function on Page B is currently trying to load the div onto Page B. I verified this by adding a copy of the div to Page B, and it loads there, as expected.

How can I make the function on Page B target the div on Page A?

On page B I'm using:

```
function functionName() {   
   $('#divName').loadfunction functionName('pageC.php');     {   
}
```

Comment: Uff! Very complicated. I'm guessing it's timing issue and certain parts of the dom aren't available when the event handlers are being set. Is there a way you could post some more html and javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming floatbox is using an iframe, and that they are both in the same domain,

`parent.$("#divName").load("pageC.php");`